Is there a way in SSRS to only display specific parts of a report when rendered in MHTML, vs when it is rendered in the Report Viewer?
I have created a fairly long SSRS report which is to be sent out daily via email and embedded in the email in MHTML format. The whole report is not necessarily needed for the email however and we'd like to keep it concise when viewed in this form. I'm wondering if there is a way to only show part of the report when it is rendered in MHTML and then the reports users can view it in the report viewer if they need the additional pages / content.
Looking at previous posts it looks like there are two inbuilt fields Globals!RenderFormat.Name and Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive that could be used in line with visibility expressions, but I haven't been able to find a workaround with either of them. Globals!RenderFormat.Name is generated after expressions are evaluated so this won't work. For example I would use:
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "MHTML", True, False) 

as a visibility expression to hide certain objects in the report when it is rendered in MHTML format, however Globals!RenderFormat.Name gets calculated later in the rendering process than visibility expressions do. As a result the applied visibility expression never finds the render format to be MHTML so keeps it visible to the user.
Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive on the other hand is generated prior to expressions are evaluated, but both of the formats that I want to use (RPL and MHTML) are considered to be interactive so I also can't use an IFF or SWITCH statement here to differentiate between the two.
Does anyone have any other potential solutions?

Can you provide a [mre] ?

Reportviewer has an event for when the Export button is clicked. Maybe you can set a variable or something before render?

If the email going going to be generated by hand, i.e. user runs the report interactively, then exports to MHTML then emails the exported file.... then I can only suggest you have a parameter with a default value that shows everything, then set a textbox to open open a URL that runs the same report but with the parameter set to 'email mode' (hiding stuff) including the renderformat, so it does the export without using the export button.

Adding to the above. In it's simplest form (from memory). The URL would look something like http://myServer/ReportServer?myReportName&myEmailModeParameter=1&rs:Command=Render&Format=MHTML

@AlanSchofield The email will be generated automatically by a scheduled subscription, and in our organisation we have a self service report portal which users can navigate to on their free will (e.g. we wouldn't be able to force users to access the report via a pre-defined URL) so I don't think this will work for us unfortunately. Unless there is a way for me to apply a parameter to a subscription

I've never tried but you might be able to set the parameter via a subscription. The URL I mentioned would be behind a button on the report itself. So the user would click the [Export to MHTML] button on the report rather than using the toolbar to export. The button would just be a textbox with an action set to "Open URL". The URL expression would be something like I posted above. If this does not help, I can try to put together q simple working example later today as an answer.

@AlanSchofield The users won't really ever be exporting it themselves, rather it will get sent via the subscription, embedded in an email via MHTML every morning. So we'd want that MHTML version to only contain part of the report, but the web / report viewer version to contain everything

@Christian Can you go with two copies of the same report? Full one for the viewer and a pared down one for subscriptions.

OK, I understand. So have a hidden ExportMode parameter that defaults to 0 and then on the subscription set the parameter to the 1. You can set parameter values in the subscription settings. When the users open the report as normal, they will not see the parameter and it will be set to 0 by default, nothing will change from their perspective.

@AlanSchofield Brilliant! That's exactly what I needed and has worked as intended. Please could you add this as an answer when you get chance?

The easiest way to do this might be to add a hidden parameter (e.g. ExportMode) and set the default value to 0, meaning 'not in export mode'.
Set Hidden property of the elements you need hiding to =Parameters!ExportMode.Value = 1
Finally, in the subscription setting, set the ExportMode parameter to 1.
Now when users open the report as normal, the parameter will be 0 and everything will be shown but when the subscription runs, the parameter will be 1 and the selected elements will be hidden.
